# api-platform adding groupig data by columns

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm new to api-platform, and I'm trying to add custom universal filter to group data by given columns.

I wrote samothing like that:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

final class GroupFilter extends AbstractFilter
{
    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {

        $parameterName = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName($property);
        $columns = explode(';',$value);
        foreach($columns as $col) {
            $queryBuilder->addGroupBy($col);
        }
    }


    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        $description = [];
//        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description['groupBy'] = [
                'property' => 'Given column names',
                'type' => 'string',
                'required' => false,
                'swagger' => ['description' => 'Grouping data - used GroupBy - separate columns with ; '],
            ];
//        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```

But in SQL I should list columns to use groupBy.
When I try to use filter I got:
 Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: It looks like a Doctrine error. Can you provide the URL you use (the column name you use)?

Comment: Do you want this: http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/drugs?groupBy=manufacturer

Now I got that response:
`"@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Class Drug does not exist",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/var/.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php",
      "line": 197,
      "args": []
    },...`